# Facebook graph API:Check if a user is online?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Now i am using NodeJS for my webhook, and i 
need to know if a Facebook user is online or not ( by user_id, user_ token ). Can't find the graph api call for this?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do that anymore since v2.0 of the Graph API:

> user_online_presence is no longer available.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0